# Comma between if conditions - python

Tags: python, binary-tree

This is python code for recursively printing a binary tree, I want to understand what the meaning of comma after print statement is...

```
# Print the tree

def PrintTree(self):
    if self.left:
      self.left.PrintTree()
    print( self.data),
    if self.right:
     self.right.PrintTree()
```

---

Comment: try removing it and see what happens

Comment: It's most likely a typo. It doesn't quite do anything since python reads it as `print(self.data), None`

Comment: It does nothing (well, it creates a one element tuple with the return value of `print`, which is `None`). I would probably think it's a typo.

Comment: @gnahum - its just a 1 element tuple, no None.

Comment: I tried removing it , and the result was the same. It probably is a type as most who replied suggested.